Can nuclear material be detonated with light?
In this question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65842/nuclear-solar-reflective-plasma-drive I propose a question to use the light from the sun to start a nuclear chain reaction to propel a spacecraft in deep space. My connective questions for Physics SE is: Can enough light be concentrated into a single point to ignite nuclear material? And could the reflective sails capture the nuclear detonations radiation be focused to ignite a secondary chain reaction for continuous propulsion where sunlight is insufficient after a distance?

No, for trivial reasons. The surface of the Sun gives off light at about 5772K, and so whatever concentration that you do, will never exceed this temperature, and this temperature is too little do much. What do you even mean by igniting a nuclear chain reaction in the first place?

@naturallyInconsistent so it is not possible to focus light into a point beyond this temperature using mirrors or reflective sail into a fine point? the nuclear light emitted could further be focused to ignite the nuclear material without the sun, explanation.

Not possible to get any higher temperature. No, you have to explain what you mean by igniting nuclear material. What nuclear process happens faster with higher temperature?

@naturallyInconsistent the focused light it already present but as the nuclear materiel passed through the highly focused light it ignites to create more radiator to be reflected. Please explain why light cannot be focused to exceed this temperature?

Are you wanting to have the light cause fusion? And why the light cannot be focused to exceed that temperature, you should check a standard textbook on thermodynamics.

Just thermodynamically you cannot focus light to be hotter than the source it comes from. There are other reasons too as shown in this somewhat silly rendition by Randall Monroe Fire from Moonlight.


I propose a question to use the light from the sun to start a nuclear chain reaction

A nuclear chain reaction (i.e. a nuclear fission reaction) is not started by light. It is usually started by a neutrons released by a naturally fissile material such as Uranium-238.
A nuclear fusion reaction, on the other hand, can be started by light. In a thermonuclear bomb the "light" is the intense X-rays released by a fission bomb, which compress and heat lithium-deuterium fuel to initiate a fusion reaction. In a similar but more controlled manner, the National Ignition Facility uses extremely high-powered ultraviolet lasers to initiate a fusion reaction.
Could a nuclear fusion reaction be initiated by concentrating sunlight ? This would not be practical. The lasers at the National Ignition Facility have powers of the order of hundreds of terawatts. Even assuming $100\%$ efficiency, you would need a reflector that was hundreds of kilometres wide to achieve this level of power. You could, of course, use sunlight to generate electricity to charge up bank of capacitors and then release this power all at once to ignite fusion fuel - this is essentially what the NIF does - but this would be technically challenging, very inefficient, and certainly too massive for a spacecraft propulsion system.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/810052/how-many-photons-are-need-to-create-an-atomic-reaction-an-to-create-an-equivilan

A useful solar sail would be massive just to be used by the sun light alone but if more radiation/light can be directed internally along with the sunlight and without, the sail would have more capability. The photons from the sun already exist and the sails would save weight one equipment needed while providing surface propulsion and used to to constantly ignite a stream of atomic fuel that feeds back into the sails.

Note that it is fundamentally not possible to use lenses or mirrors to concentrate sunlight on a point to yield a temperature greater than that of the source (in this case, the sun's photosphere). If you could, then you could build a solar-driven heat engine which would be a perpetual motion machine.
The photosphere temperature is insufficient to trigger neither fission nor fusion. If it were, then solar fusion and fission reactions would be observed in the photosphere- which they are not.

your not considering the fuel, the sun is not composed of uranium at its center of fusion or fission process. It would take pressure and heat for the sun, but a certain amount of photons for uranium.

I will retract my excepted answer if you can make sense to me why it is not possible to used focus sunlight to start a nuclear chain reaction.
